# Segmentation fault at search_cron()

Tags: search, drush, cron

Whenever I try to run cron on the search, using

```
drush php-eval 'search_cron();'
```

I get 'Segmentation fault' error. I have not this problem for any other tables. The site contains hundreds of text-heavy nodes. So I appreciate your hint to cope with the problem.

Comment: Hi @alfish were you able to fix the above issue, I do get the same issue which prevents from indexing of the site

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is a memory error. If increasing your memory limit doesn't work, you might get relief from lowering the number of nodes to index per cron run on the search settings page.

It could also be caused by running an out-of-date version of PHP.